# Converting ActiveX controls into windows form controls

Tags: activex, ms-office, windows-controls

I have an excel sheet with activeX controls. Since ActiveX controls do not function from outside of trusted locations in versions MS Office 2007 and higher, I am supposed to convert the controls into Windows form controls. My excel sheet is password protected. I need to understand the code difference. Please guide me how to proceed. If there's any tool for fast conversion, that will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  You will have more chance at getting help if you provide the code you have tried.  Asking for tools etc is off topic on SO

Comment: This is so new to me that I do not understand what code difference can an activex control have from a windows form control.Can you redirect me to any link that helps with identification of activeX controls?I'll then try how I can convert them.

Comment: That is where you need to start learning them - I would suggest using the search here (and maybe SuperUser.SE).  Look up your heading as a search term in Google.

Comment: I have searched a lot but couldn't find any link relevant to my work. superuser.se looks like an album?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm now creating a new excel sheet and replacing the activeX controls by windows form controls and coding again. I guess that should work.

Comment: Can I just save the converted .xls as an .XLT file and it would work?